# Peformance difference due to type instability?

Tags: julia

I am trying the following code in Julia 0.4-prerelease, which performs matrix exponentiation in two different ways (exact vs series expansion). I tried using several methods for getting the array dimension `n` and setting unit matrices `eye( n )`.

```
function test()
    A = [ 1.0 -1.0 ; -1.0  1.0 ]

    lam, U = eig( A )                         # diagonalization: A U = U diagm(lam)

    Bref = U * diagm( exp(lam) ) * U'         # Bref = exp(A) (in matrix sense)

    #[ Get the dimension n ]                            
    n = length( lam )                                                  # slow (1a)
    # const n = length( lam )                                          # slow (1b)
    # n::Int = length( lam )                                           # fast (1c)
    # const n::Int = length( lam )                                     # fast (1d)
    # n = size( A, 1 )                                                 # fast (1e)

    #[ Set unit matrices to B and X ]
    B = eye( n ); X = eye( n )                                         # slow with (1a) (2-1)
    # B = eye( 2 ); X = eye( 2 )                                       # fast (2-2)
    # B = eye( n::Int ); X = eye( n::Int )                             # fast (2-3) 
    # B::Array{Float64,2} = eye( n ); X::Array{Float64,2} = eye( n )   # fast (2-4)
    # B = eye( A ); X = eye( A )                                       # fast (2-5)

    #[ Calc B = exp(A) with Taylor expansion ]
    @time for k = 1:20
        X[:,:] = X * A / float( k )
        B[:,:] += X
    end

    #[ Check error ]
    @show norm( B - Bref )
end

test()
```

Here I observed that when n is a dynamic variable (without type annotation), the code becomes much slower than otherwise. For example, the combination of (1a) and (2-1) gives
the "slow" result below, while other combinations give the "fast" result (more than 1000 times faster).

```
slow case => elapsed time: 0.043822985 seconds (1 MB allocated)
fast case => elapsed time: 1.1702e-5 seconds (16 kB allocated)
```

Is this because "type instability" occurs inside for-loop? I am confused because `eye( n )` is always `Array{Float64,2}` (only used in the initialization) and there seems to be no (implicit) change of types. Also confusing is that the combination of (1e) and (2-1) is fast, where dynamic `n` is set with size() rather than length(). Overall, to obtain good performance, is it better to annotate array-dimension variables explicitly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the difference is primarily from compilation time. If I put another two `test()`s I get the following:

With `2-1` and `1a`:

```
  73.599 milliseconds (70583 allocations: 3537 KB)
norm(B - Bref) = 4.485301019485633e-14
  15.165 microseconds (200 allocations: 11840 bytes)
norm(B - Bref) = 4.485301019485633e-14
  10.844 microseconds (200 allocations: 11840 bytes)
norm(B - Bref) = 4.485301019485633e-14
```

With `2-2` and `1a`:

```
   8.662 microseconds (180 allocations: 11520 bytes)
norm(B - Bref) = 4.485301019485633e-14
   7.968 microseconds (180 allocations: 11520 bytes)
norm(B - Bref) = 4.485301019485633e-14
   7.654 microseconds (180 allocations: 11520 bytes)
norm(B - Bref) = 4.485301019485633e-14
```

The difference in compilation times though is coming from different code being compiled. That, and the remaining small some differences in time, is actually coming from a type instability. Check out this part of `@code_warntype test()` for the `1a` version:

```
  GenSym(0) = (Base.LinAlg.__eig#214__)(GenSym(19),A::Array{Float64,2})::Tuple{Any,Any}
  #s8 = 1
  GenSym(22) = (Base.getfield)(GenSym(0),1)::Any
  GenSym(23) = (Base.box)(Base.Int,(Base.add_int)(1,1)::Any)::Int64
  lam = GenSym(22)
  #s8 = GenSym(23)
  GenSym(24) = (Base.getfield)(GenSym(0),2)::Any
  GenSym(25) = (Base.box)(Base.Int,(Base.add_int)(2,1)::Any)::Int64
  U = GenSym(24)
  #s8 = GenSym(25) # line 7:
  Bref = U * (Main.diagm)((Main.exp)(lam)::Any)::Any * (Main.ctranspose)(U)::Any::Any # line 9:
  n = (Main.length)(lam)::Any # line 11:
  B = (Main.eye)(n)::Any # line 11:
  X = (Main.eye)(n)::Any # line 13: # util.jl, line 170:
```

I read that as type inference failing to figure out the return type of `eig`. This then propagates through to B and X. If you add `n::Int`, the last lines change to

```
  n = (top(typeassert))((top(convert))(Main.Int,(Main.length)(lam)::Any)::Any,Main.Int)::Int64 # line 11:
  B = (Base.eye)(Base.Float64,n::Int64,n::Int64)::Array{Float64,2} # line 11:
  X = (Base.eye)(Base.Float64,n::Int64,n::Int64)::Array{Float64,2} # line 13: # util.jl, line 170:
```

So `B` and `X` are typed correctly. [An issue about this exact subject was raised recently](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/12304) - it doesn't really seem like there is much option except annotating it yourself if you want to get maximum performance.

Comment: Hmm.. I also obtained the same results (the 2nd and 3rd calls for test() became "fast"). I imagined that the JIT compiler first compiles this file as a whole and measures the the calculation time for for-loop, but in fact the compilation is performed on the fly for much smaller code blocks and @time includes such compilation time (as you explained)?

Comment: Time absolutely includes compilation, and also the memory allocated for the compiled functions as well.

Comment: I've updated my answer to be clearer about why different code is even being compiled in the first place.

Comment: Yeah thanks very much. Now I understand the difference is mainly from compilation time. Also I have read the pages you linked (and another page linked from there), and there seems subtle issue about eig()... (and the output of @code_warntype is very complicated @@;) Anyway, the appearance of "Any" seems a warning flag. Thanks very much :D

Comment: Try running with `julia --color=yes` - the `Any`s will pop out bright red!